# How to check connection errors to RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I've installed RabbitMQ and I'm able to initiate a connection successfully. I do it like this:

```php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($config_hostnameRabbitmqConnection, $config_portRabbitmqConnection, $config_usernameRabbitmqConnection, $config_passwordRabbitmqConnection);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
```

I'm trying to catch the errors in the case something goes wrong. How to do it in this case if the connection isn't made? I usually check stuff using `empty()` , `isset()` and the try and catch way. In this case however, there isn't really something to check for emptiness or so. Do I use try and catch or is there something else that is better in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think RabbitMQ has a default way of handling errors. You could do

```
    try {
      $channel = $connection->channel();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("I could not create a connection");
    }
```

Is this what you are looking for?